# How to maintain sequence number for particular record for longer time even if number of records inserted in order?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How to maintain sequence number for same record for longer time even if number of 
records inserted

I want to insert the sequence number in reference_id column for same customer with different territory name

```
   Row_id     customer_name    customer_id     territory     reference_id
      1            A             100             USA           5000
      2            B             200             UK            5500
      3            C             300             LA            6000
      4            A             100             CANADA        5001    
      5            B             200             CONGO         5501
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (The answer won't be the same...)

Comment: @jarlh,oracle12c

Comment: On what basis are these series 5000, 5500, 6000 ..etc determined for A,B and C?

Comment: Do you want query that can keep the seq number for future insertions or you want update query to update the current ref number in order to create a sequence?

Comment: @Harshil i just want to keep the sequence order for same record